# modify the return address to shellcode

Tags: c, assembly, buffer, buffer-overflow, exploit

i have tow C program. one is shellcode and the other vulnerable program.

i want to change the return address with out buffering the vulnerable program.

like for example:-

`__asm__("movl $shellcode, 4(%ebp)");`

but this method doesn't work for me, i have tried running the vulnerable program in linux with gdb and redirect shellcode to it `(gdb) run vuln < shellcode` but eip or ebp never change.
can someone look at my shellcode program and see where's the error is.

shellcode program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void shellcode() {
__asm__(".byte 0x90,0x90,0x90,0x90,0x90,0x90,0x90,0x90"); /* you may put your shellcode here */
printf("hey guyz!\n");
exit(0);
}

void bang(int val) {

__asm__("movl $shellcode, 4(%ebp)");

}

int main() {
bang(0);
}
```

vulnerable program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int bof(char *string) {

char buffer[1024];

strcpy(buffer, string);

return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

bof(argv[1]);
printf("Done..\n");

return 1;
}
```

Comment: can you please describe the expected behavior?

Comment: @AB_, the program running normal and print printf("Done").after injecting shellcode to it, nothing change. i think the problem in shellcode. can you check please at your end.

Comment: doesn't print "Done"? doesn't copy the string? please be specific

Comment: @AB_,it printing "Done". that's all

Comment: what did you expect?

Comment: @AB_,i expect to print the shellcode after injecting it to the program.but that not happening

Comment: how do you "injecting"? You should describe us what are you doing, how do you call and what if you want someone to help.

Comment: @AB_,i already describe this in my question please read it carefully,im using linux gdb to inject the shellcode program into vulnerable program like this `(gdb) run vuln < shellcode`

Comment: Your "shellcode" is a standalone program that you can run and it will overwrite its own return address as a demonstration. You can't use that as input to your vulnerable program and expect anything sensible. Also, the vulnerable program processes command line argument, does not read stdin so your redirection has absolutely no effect. Do some more studying, you are missing too many pieces we can't explain in a short SO answer.

Comment: @Jester, thank you Jester for your explanation, but how i can change the return address with out buffering the program? do i have to write external program in C language and feed it to the vulnerable program? if im going to use perl with linux gdb, perl doesn't not support Assembly language. im confused here.please clarify to me..how im going to feed the vulnerable program with the new return address`(shellcode)`.

Comment: You need to translate the shellcode to raw bytes that you can then feed into the program as input. Also note that nowadays there are various protections in place that stop you from using trivial exploits. To just see that you can overwrite the return address, pass a string of sufficient length as input. Example: `run $(perl -e 'print "A"x1200')` should give you a fault at address `0x41414141` showing the return address has been overwritten.

Comment: @Jester, can you please be specific which data type shell i use to convert my shellcode. i couldn't understand whats  the meaning of raw bytes. do you mean hex data type or decimal or binary data.can you please refer to tools based on linux for converting.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is called a [Stack buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow).

Basically,
You write into your stack more bytes than you should and overwrite the return address.

When you enter a function the stack looks something like this (simplified):

```
  +----------------+
  | Buffer[0]      |
  | Buffer[1]      |
  | .              |
  | .              |
  | .              |
  | Buffer[1023]   |
  | Return Address |
  +----------------+
```

So, you have to write al least 1025 bytes to reach the return address.
Once you do that and the function returns, it will try to return to whatever value you've put there.

Here's an example:

say that we have a file named "exploit.txt" filled with 32 A's: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

and the vulnerable program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(FILE *f)
{
   long size;
   char c[12];  // You should only write 12 bytes here
   fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
   size = ftell(f);
   rewind(f);
   fread(c, 1, size, f);    // no bounds checking
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   FILE *f = NULL;
   if(f = open("exploit.txt", "r"))
   {
      func(f);
      fclose(f);
   }

   printf("done.\n");
   return 0;
}
```

When your run the program, you'll crash at address 0x41414141 since reading the file caused an overflow and the return address was overwritten.

In this type of exploit your shellcode will have a specific return address at the beginning,
pointing to a place in the vulnerable executable which than jumps back to your shellcode on the stack (`jmp esp`).

Note however, that most likely, this won't work with modern compilers since they add [security checks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection) to prevent exactly that,
So if You want to try it you'll have to disable those options in your compiler.

You might also want to read more about [Buffer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Buffer_overflow_protection)

Hope that helps!